# How to get an android activity name using java?

Tags: java, android

In my android app, if I have an activity called `Home.java`, how could I get the string `"Home"` on the oncreate event of that activity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
this.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

Comment: hi Omega, if this solved your problem please mark it as solved